# Live search field write back

Tags: sapui5

I have a SearchField with liveChange properties:

```
<SearchField id="searchField" liveChange="onSearch" width="100%" />
```

In my controller i manage the live-action:

```
onSearch : function (oEvt) {

        // add filter for search
        var aFilters = [];
        var sQuery = oEvt.getSource().getValue();
        if (sQuery && sQuery.length > 0) {
          var fileterCol=this.byId("selectSearch789").getSelectedKey();
          var filter = new sap.ui.model.Filter(fileterCol, sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.Contains, sQuery);
          aFilters.push(filter);
        }

        // update list binding
        var tableArtConNom = this.getView().byId("tableResult");
        var binding = tableArtConNom.getBinding("items");
        binding.filter(aFilters, "Application");
    }
```

But at every char that I write, the cursor return al position 0. For example if I want search HOUSE i write the word but i see ESUOH....

If i use `search` and not `liveChange` it work!

Comment: I think you're suffering from something else... the code in the `onSearch` method doesn't indicate anything wrong. Do you somewhere else set the focus to the control? See this sample http://jsbin.com/ditado/1/edit?js,console,output using the code you provided (I commented out the parts to other controls)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a solution for you. Please set property of SearchField: **selectOnFocus="false"**.

Please also see the [documentation](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/entity/sap.m.SearchField/properties).

Regards,
Allen